# Regarding non Breaking of If statement

Tags: if-statement

I have written the If statement code:

```
if(holidays.get(market) == null || !holidays.get(market).containsKey(tempDate)) {
                    tempDate = tempDate.addDays(1);
                }
```

The code will execute until the condition fails ? How is it possible? what i have to use

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: Replace `if` with `while`.

Comment: @EvanTrimboli No it is not working, My scenario - until all the conditon fails only it should exit the loop, if one condition true also, it have to add days